# Why doesn't throw an error this union based type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have in my TypeScript project a situation which could be simplified with the following:

Consider the following type `Type`:

```typescript
type Type = {
  a: number;
} | {
  a: number;
  b: number;
} | {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
};
```

I can define the `t` constant based on `Type` type:

```typescript
const t: Type = {
  a: 1,
  c: 3
};
```

And **it doesn't give me any error**! Due the `Type` type definition, I couldn't define an object with `a` and `c` properties. But I can. Why?

Moreover, if I access `c` property:

```typescript
console.log(t.c);
```

It gives me a transpitation error saying:

```text
Property 'c' does not exist on type 'Type'. Property 'c' does not exist on type '{ a: number; }'.
```

I really don't know what's going on!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript uses [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

1. Problem: **Excess property check** : The quirk of excess property checks is that for unions, it allows any property from any union constituent to be present in the assigned object literal.

`const t: Type = {  a: 1,  c: 3 };` is valid because it conforms to the first part of you union  `{ a: number; }`.

This won't happen if the types don't match: for exemple :

```
type Type = {
    a: number;
    b: number
} | {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: number;
};

let t: Type = {  // KO 
    a: 1,
    c: 3
};
```

More on that topic :  [Excess Property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#improved-excess-property-checks-in-union-types)

2., `console.log(t.c);`, TS will warn you that the key `c` does not exist on every part of your union, hence the error message you see.

You can fix this with [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), an particularly the `in` operator :

```
if('c' in t) {
   console.log(t.c) // OK
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BQUNQIYC4oDsBXAWwCMIAnAblQF8oAfFdTXAk86ljUvIsyjXpM0mbHw6DuUXuwFcxAYwnyhNVIoD2%20AM7AowPHEhQko1ngCMAGmnKoAZjrqAlgDMoACgDki71Bd8AwBKZiVtHU0AGwgAOijNAHNPYFjFYKEgA)

Comment: `type Type = { a: number } | { b: number }` and `const t: Type = { a: 1, c: 2 }`, gives the error: 'Type '{ a: number; c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Type''. Although 'it conforms to the first part of you union'

Comment: @JoséAntonioPostigo, in this example, your union does not overlap !

Comment: Ok, this union does overlap: `type Type = { a: number } | { a: number, b: number };` and it gives the same error for `const t: Type = { a: 1, c: 2 }`.